# MVC 4 Ajax.BeginForm and ModelState.AddModelError

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to get errors to show up after an ajax submit has returned an error. I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I can't get it to work. This question is basically the same thing - [ModelState.AddModelError is not being displayed inside my view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406998/modelstate-addmodelerror-is-not-being-displayed-inside-my-view) but I'm still not having any luck. My experience with Ajax and MVC (any version) is still a bit limited. Here is a very simple example, most of which I took from the previous link.

View: test.cshtml

```
@model TestProject.VisitLabResult

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")

@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        Url = Url.Action("test"),
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        LoadingElementId = "loading",
        LoadingElementDuration = 500,
        OnSuccess = "processData"
    };
}
@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")


<div id="loading" class="load" style="display:none">
    <p>Saving...</p>
</div>

<table>
@for (int item = 0; item < 10; item++)
{
    <tr id = @item>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxOpts))
    {  
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </td>

        <td id = @(item.ToString() + "td")>
        </td>
    }
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Controller: HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult test()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult test(VisitLabResult vlr, int visitid = 28)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                throw new Exception("error");
            }
            else
                return View(vlr);
        }
        else
            return View(vlr);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "The Same test Type might have been already created, go back to the Visit page to see the available Lab Tests");
        return View(vlr);
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class VisitLabResult
{
    public int visitid { get; set; }
}
```

If it is an Ajax request I throw an error and it's caught and an error is added to ModelState. That error never shows up on the page though. Am I approaching this the right way at all? Or do I need to take a different route? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Found this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7329127/978528) after more searching and that seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the solution for other people hitting this question. The ajax helper fires `OnSuccess` vs `OnFailure` based on the returned HTTP Code per the [`AjaxOptions` docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.aspx):

> [`OnSuccess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onsuccess.aspx): This function is called if the response status **is** in the 200 range.
>   [`OnFailure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onfailure.aspx): This function is called if the response status **is not** in the 200 range.

In other words, you have to manually specify that there was a failure when returning your ActionResult by changing the `Response.StatusCode` and then returning whatever values you're expecting in your `OnFailure` js method.  You can drive that based on any business logic you want (i.e. `catch Exception ex)` or `!ModelState.IsValid` ...)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(Person model) 
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    // if valid, return a HTML view inserted by AJAX helper
    var results = PersonRepository.Get(model)
    return PartialView("Resulsts", vm);

  } else {
    // if invalid, return a JSON object and handle with OnFailure method
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    return Json(new { errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors) });

  }
}
```

**Further Reading**:

- [MVC 4 Ajax.BeginForm and ModelState.AddModelError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21311026/1366033)
- [ASP.NET MVC “Ajax.BeginForm” executes OnSuccess even though model is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7328977/1366033)